# Converting array to filelist makes file-size 0

Tags: javascript

I have an array that looks like:

```
Array [ "state/file1.xlsx", "state/file2.xlsx" ]
```

I am trying to convert this array to filelist with below method:

```
function createFileList(files) {
        var fileListTextarea = document.getElementById('uploaded_files');
        var files = fileListTextarea.value.trim().split('\n');
        var dataTransfer = new DataTransfer();
        files.forEach(function (fileKey) {
            var fileName = fileKey.split('/').pop(); 
            var file = new File([], fileName);
            dataTransfer.items.add(file);
        });
        return dataTransfer.files;
    }
```

This conversion makes the filesize to 0.

```
FileList [ File, File ]
0: File { name: "file1.xlsx", lastModified: 1710863577685, size: 0, … }
1: File { name: "file2.xlsx", lastModified: 1710863577685, size: 0, … }
```

how to convert an array to file list without losing the filesize? the file object is not getting created correctly. any help?

Comment: nothing is lost here either your files are created by themselves with `new File` with no content so size = 0 bytes

Comment: can you elaborate more?

Comment: `new File([], fileName);`  creates a file object with the given name (second parameter) and the given content (first parameter). The content is empty.

Comment: is there a way to include file content in this conversion process?

Comment: Where should the content come from? Are you trying to read the contents of the named files? JavaScript in the browser isn't allowed to do this, you can only access files selected by the user in a file picker dialog.

Comment: i have an input(file select button) and a text area. everytime i select a file, it gets listed on the text area like "file1","file2",etc. I want to loop through the text area to upload the file to s3 but when i do a DOM read of text area, they all come as an array. I'm trying to convert that array into filelist

Comment: when i read the filelistarea it appears to be an array Array [ "state/file1.xlsx", "state/file2.xlsx" ]